# Set up a filtered query using an array and return a series of calculations in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, foreach, vba, do-while

The task: Create a report for Part Numbers that shows several types (On Hand, On Order, etc) in date buckets with each type totaled for the specific range.

```
For example: 
Item 1 => (could be over 2000)
                2/5/2017    2/19/2017    2/28/2017 (30 weeks)
On Hand           20           42           33
On Order           0            5            4
```

Each item is shown on it's own page with related metadata about the item. Each date bucket is based on a user-entered start date with a calculation running against the data set to determine what goes in which bucket and what the totals are.

I have this report fully working for one item. User types one item, selects a date, and the report is created using the following:

```
Inventory Meta general information and description of the item
Inventory Detail gets all the detailed information 
Inventory Totals gets totals for each Types 
GetInventory() VBA sets up the buckets and populates the totals
```

Using a query to get the date buckets would perhaps be easier to get the data into the report. Creating a query with 210 calculated columns (7 types, 30 weeks) wasn't a reasonable approach.

Naturally, selecting one item at a time is not what's wanted.

I have a select box that gets whatever Part Numbers are selected and creates a query on the fly for the Inventory Meta (main report). I have similar code working that runs with the Inventory Totals (sub report) to create a query on the fly for that.

But, as with the Inventory Totals query, each date is a unique value and is it's own row. What I need to be able to do is run the code to build the buckets for each item selected.

I'm stuck.

I have created an array of item numbers (whatever was selected). I can see what's in the array.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to feed each to the code that runs the date comparisons and calculations so that I get a full set of data for each Part Number.

With one number it was easy.... "this one"

```
vItem = [Forms]![fOptions]![ItemNumber]
Set db = CurrentDb
    strSelect = "Select * FROM qInventoryTotals WHERE qInventoryTotals.ItemNumber = [this_one]"
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSelect)
    qdf.Parameters("this_one").Value = vItem
Set inv = qdf.OpenRecordset
```

The closest I've come is getting the report to show the same set of data for all part numbers. I suspect there is some small but critical thing, like where a particular loop starts or a variable I've missed or something.

The result of the following is a message box that repeats the same total for each of the part numbers.

```
    Private Sub CreateOne_Click()

On Error GoTo Err_cmdOpenQuery_Click

'----------- Selection box check for dates -------------
If IsNull(Forms!fFish1!Week1) Then
        MsgBox "A Sunday date must be selected", , "Please select a date"
    ElseIf Weekday(Forms!fFish1!Week1) = 1 Then
        'MsgBox "That is Sunday"
       Forms!fFish1!Week1 = Forms!fFish1!Week1
    Else
        MsgBox "Starting Week needs to be a Sunday date" _
               , , "Sorry, that's not Sunday"
        ' clears the 'not Sunday' selection
        Forms!fFish1!Week1 = ""
    Exit Sub
 End If
'-------------------------------------------------
' Declarations =====================================

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim iMeta As DAO.QueryDef

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strWhere As String
    Dim strIN As String
    Dim flgSelectAll As Boolean
    Dim varItem As Variant

    Dim strSlect As String
    Dim vItem As Variant


' Setup  -------------------------------------
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qInventoryTotals2"

'----------------------------------------------------------------------
' Get whatever is selected and loop through the selections
' This defines which numbers are in the list
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
    For i = 0 To Forms!fFish1.box4.ListCount - 1
        If Forms!fFish1.box4.Selected(i) Then
            If Forms!fFish1.box4.Column(0, i) = "All" Then
                flgSelectAll = True
            End If
            strIN = strIN & "'" & Forms!fFish1.box4.Column(0, i) & "',"
        End If
    Next i

    'Create the WHERE string, and strip off the last comma of the IN string
    strWhere = " WHERE [ItemNumber] in " & _
               "(" & Left(strIN, Len(strIN) - 1) & ")"

    'If "All" was selected in the listbox, don't add the WHERE condition
    If Not flgSelectAll Then
       strSQL = strSQL & strWhere
    End If
'-------------------------------------------------------

' Create a query that has all the selected item numbers
    db.QueryDefs.Delete "qInventoryTotals3"
    Set iMeta = db.CreateQueryDef("qInventoryTotals3", strSQL)

    Set inv = iMeta.OpenRecordset

'==========================================================================
' Create an array to pull out each of the Item numbers one at a time
Dim Count As Integer, r As Integer
Count = 0

For i = 0 To Forms!fFish1.box4.ListCount - 1
        If Forms!fFish1.box4.Selected(i) Then
            vItem = Forms!fFish1.box4.Column(0, i)
            'vItemFilter = Forms!fFish1.box4.Column(0, i)
            'MsgBox (vItem), , "one by one"
            Count = Count + 1
       End If
    Next i

''MsgBox (Count), , "count how many items are in the set"
' Get the count for how many items are in the currently selected list
' Displays one item at a time -

' Set up the array ------------------------------
'------------------------------------------------
ReDim vItem(Count)
    r = 0

    For i = 0 To Forms!fFish1.box4.ListCount - 1
      If Forms!fFish1.box4.Selected(i) Then
            vItem(r) = Forms!fFish1.box4.Column(0, i)
            r = r + 1
       End If
    Next i


    'Check the values stored in array
    ''For i = 0 To Count - 1
       ''MsgBox vItem(i), , "show all values from the array"
    ''Next
' have all values from the array. Each in it's own message box
'===============================================================================

' Set up the item numbers ---------------------------

Dim part As Variant
part = vItem

  With vItem
       For i = LBound(vItem) To UBound(vItem) - 1
       MsgBox ("There are" & " " & (vItem(i)) & " " & "fishies"), , "Whatcha' got now?"

' cycles through each number

' Past Due ============================================
Dim tPOPast As Double
Dim tBCPast As Double
Dim tBPast As Double
Dim tEPast As Double

    If inv!ItemNumber = part(i) And inv.Fields("RequiredDate") < Forms!fFish1!Week1 Then
    'displays the first part number with it's value, then the remaining numbers with no value

'    If inv.Fields("RequiredDate") < Forms!fFish1!Week1 Then
    'displays each of the part numbers with the same value


        tBPast = inv.Fields("TotalOnHand")
        tPOPast = tPOPast + inv.Fields("SumOfSupply")
        tBCPast = tBCPast + inv.Fields("SumOfDemand")

' Calculate ending inventory for the week ===================
        tEPast = tBPast + tPOPast + tBCPast 

' Show something for testing ==============================

        MsgBox (tBPast & " " & part(i)), , "show Me the money" ' displays same total for each part number

    End If 
'end this condition, next condition follows
'----------------- do it again -------------------------------
    Next

' Finished with the weekly buckets =====================================

    End With
'=========================================================================

'-------------------- error management for the selection box ------------------
Exit_cmdOpenQuery_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdOpenQuery_Click:

    If Err.Number = 5 Then
        MsgBox "Pick one, or more, item numbers from the list" _
               , , "Gotta pick something!"
        Resume Exit_cmdOpenQuery_Click

    Else
        'Write out the error and exit the sub
        MsgBox Err.Description
        Resume Exit_cmdOpenQuery_Click
    End If
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to set variables for the values from the array and use them to dynamically update a table. From that, I created a query to sum the values and used that as the basis for the report. The key was `GetRows()`

Get the unique items and read the the rows of data into the first array

```
    Dim rNum As Integer

rNum = myItems.RecordCount

    Dim varItem As Variant
    Dim intRi As Integer  'rows of unique items
    Dim intCi As Integer  'columns of unique items
    Dim intNCi As Integer
    Dim intRCi As Integer

varItem = myItems.GetRows(rNum)
    intNRi = UBound(varItem, 2) + 1
    intNCi = UBound(varItem, 1) + 1

For intRi = 0 To intNRi - 1
    For intCi = 0 To intNCi - 1
    vItem = varItem(intCi, intRi)
```

Use `vItem` to dynamically create a new recordset to set up the weekly buckets

```
    strSelect = "Select * FROM qInventoryTotals2 WHERE qInventoryTotals2.ItemNumber = [this_one]"
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSelect)
    qdf.Parameters("this_one").Value = vItem
Set inv = qdf.OpenRecordset
```

Count the records, create a second array

```
    Dim invNum As Integer

invNum = inv.RecordCount

    Dim varRec As Variant
    Dim intR As Integer
    Dim intC As Integer
    Dim intNC As Integer
    Dim intRC As Integer

    Dim cItem As String
    Dim cRequired As Date
    Dim cPO As Double
    Dim cBC As Double
    Dim cOnHand As Double

varRec = inv.GetRows(invNum)
    intNR = UBound(varRec, 2) + 1
    intNC = UBound(varRec, 1) + 1

For intR = 0 To intNR - 1
    For intC = 0 To intNC - 1

        cItem = varRec(0, intR)
        cRequired = varRec(1, intR)
        cOnHand = varRec(2, intR)
        cPO = varRec(3, intR)
        cBC = varRec(4, intR)
        cSO = varRec(5, intR)
        cPD = varRec(6, intR)
        cIN = varRec(7, intR)
        cJT = varRec(8, intR)
        cWO = varRec(9, intR)


'------------- finish getting inventory columns --------------------
    Next intC
```

And then set up the buckets for each week

```
    If cRequired < Week1 Then

        recOut.AddNew
        recOut.Fields("ItemNumber") = cItem
        recOut.Fields("tB") = cOnHand
        recOut.Fields("tPO") = cPO
        recOut.Fields("tBC") = cBC
        recOut.Fields("tSO") = cSO
        recOut.Fields("tPD") = cPD
        recOut.Fields("tIN") = cIN
        recOut.Fields("tJT") = cJT
        recOut.Fields("tWO") = cWO
        recOut.Fields("tE") = cOnHand + cPO + cBC + cSO + cPD + cIN + cJT + cWO
        recOut.Fields("RequiredDate") = cRequired
        recOut.Fields("GroupDate") = Week1
        recOut.Update

'        tE0 = cOnHand + cPO + cBC + cSO + cPD + cIN + cJT + cWO

Dim tryme As Double
        tryme = DLookup("teMe", "qBuckets", "GroupDate = Week1")
        tE0 = tryme

   End If
```